Expand a dataframe row into multiple rows based on string conditions
I have some raw data similar to the dataframe below:

df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': '220-224 (Even) roadname1', 'var2': 'location 1', 'var3': 'area 1'},
                   {'var1': 'site of 5 to 9 (odd) roadname2', 'var2': 'location 2', 'var3': 'area 2'},
                  {'var1': '16, 19 roadname3', 'var2': 'location 3', 'var3': 'area 3'}]
                 )
df

var1    var2    var3
0   220-224 (Even) roadname1    location 1  area 1
1   site of 5 to 9 (odd) roadname2  location 2  area 2
2   16, 19 roadname3    location 3  area 3

I would like to write a function that will split the var1 strings so that each number indicated becomes a separate row in the dataframe, with an output such as:

df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': '220 roadname1', 'var2': 'location 1', 'var3': 'area 1'},
                   {'var1': '222 roadname1', 'var2': 'location 1', 'var3': 'area 1'},
                   {'var1': '224 roadname1', 'var2': 'location 1', 'var3': 'area 1'},
                   {'var1': '5 roadname2', 'var2': 'location 2', 'var3': 'area 2'},
                  {'var1': '7 roadname2', 'var2': 'location 2', 'var3': 'area 2'},
                  {'var1': '9 roadname2', 'var2': 'location 2', 'var3': 'area 2'},
                  {'var1': '16 roadname3', 'var2': 'location 3', 'var3': 'area 3'},
                  {'var1': '19 roadname3', 'var2': 'location 3', 'var3': 'area 3'},]
                 )
df

var1    var2    var3
0   220 roadname1   location 1  area 1
1   222 roadname1   location 1  area 1
2   224 roadname1   location 1  area 1
3   5 roadname2     location 2  area 2
4   7 roadname2     location 2  area 2
5   9 roadname2     location 2  area 2
6   16 roadname3    location 3  area 3
7   19 roadname3    location 3  area 3

the string conditions are a bit variable with capitalization and number ranges and I am not sure if there is an efficient way to do this that can handle the string variation.

Could you please explain why the last row of the expected output is 19 instead of 18? Should not the numbers be incremented by 2?

@PaulS presumably 16, 19 should yield those two exact values; if you had 9, 5, 12 then this should be those 3 specific values. Check my answer for an example.

It is unclear whether that is the right interpretation, @mozway. For instance, in my country, one side of the streets doors are odd numbered, while the in the other side doors are even numbered.

Use a custom function to split the ranges (below is an example using regular expressions), then explode:
import re

def parse_range(s):
    # handle the "x-y" / "x to y" case with optional odd/even
    pat1 = r'^\D*(\d+)(?:-|\s+to\s+)(\d+)(?:\s*\((even|odd)\))?\s*(.*)$'
    # handle the "a,b,c" case
    pat2 = r'^\D*([\d ,]+)\s*(.*)$'
    m1 = re.search(pat1, s.lower())
    if m1:
        end = m1.group(4)
        if m1.group(3): # if odd/even only generate every other value
            # NB. there is no check that odd/even actually matches the
            # parity of the numbers, but it is easy to add if needed
            return [f'{i} {end}' for i in
                    range(int(m1.group(1)), int(m1.group(2))+1, 2)]
        else: # generate all numbers in range
            return [f'{i} {end}' for i in
                    range(int(m1.group(1)), int(m1.group(2))+1)]
    m2 = re.search(pat2, s.lower())
    if m2: # second case, split individual digits
        end = m2.group(2)
        return [f'{i} {end}' for i in re.findall(r'\d+', m2.group(1))]
    return s # failback, return the string unchanged
    
out = (df.assign(var1=df['var1'].map(parse_range))
         .explode('var1')
      )

Output:
            var1        var2    var3
0  220 roadname1  location 1  area 1
0  222 roadname1  location 1  area 1
0  224 roadname1  location 1  area 1
1    5 roadname2  location 2  area 2
1    7 roadname2  location 2  area 2
1    9 roadname2  location 2  area 2
2   16 roadname3  location 3  area 3
2   19 roadname3  location 3  area 3

regex 1 demo
regex 2 demo

for this i'm getting the number sequience as +1 even when it's specified evens only - do you know why that might be happening?

@suzanne if you read my code carefully, you'll see that I simplified the parity check assuming the start/end numbers will have the correct parity (meaning excluding cases like 1-3 (even). Those could be handled by a simple modification of the code though.

Got it, thanks.  After testing out both, the regex help handle the cases more accurately - thanks!

A possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it uses str.extractall to extract all digit sequences from var1, resulting in a dataframe d with a MultiIndex.

Then, it employs xs to select the first two matches (levels 0 and 1) from d, concatenates them along the columns using pd.concat, and converts them to integers.

Next, it applies a lambda function to create a range from the first to the second number, incrementing by 2, and assigns this range to a new 'aux' column.

The dataframe is then exploded with explode to expand each range into separate rows.

Subsequently, it uses pipe to assign a new 'aux' column by concatenating the string representation of the range values with the last word extracted from var1 using str.extract with expand=False.

Finally, the dataframe is reset to a default integer index with reset_index, dropping the old index.


d = df['var1'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')
(df.assign(
    aux = pd.concat([d.xs(i, level=1) for i in [0, 1]], axis=1)
    .astype(int)
    .apply(lambda x: range(x.iloc[0], x.iloc[1] + 1, 2), axis=1))
 .explode('aux').pipe(
     lambda x: x.assign(
         aux=x['aux'].astype(str) + ' ' + x['var1'].str.extract(r'(\w+)$', expand=False)))
 .reset_index(drop=True))

Output:
                             var1        var2    var3            aux
0        220-224 (Even) roadname1  location 1  area 1  220 roadname1
1        220-224 (Even) roadname1  location 1  area 1  222 roadname1
2        220-224 (Even) roadname1  location 1  area 1  224 roadname1
3  site of 5 to 9 (odd) roadname2  location 2  area 2    5 roadname2
4  site of 5 to 9 (odd) roadname2  location 2  area 2    7 roadname2
5  site of 5 to 9 (odd) roadname2  location 2  area 2    9 roadname2
6                16, 19 roadname3  location 3  area 3   16 roadname3
7                16, 19 roadname3  location 3  area 3   18 roadname3


This is not really matching the expected logic, this gives too many rows. I don't think using pure pandas is the way to go here.

Thanks, @mozway. I think my fault is that I missed that the step of the numbers is 2 (and not sequential, as I considered). I am going to fix that!

It is now fixed, @mozway!

Thanks, this is helpful!  I'm still running into problems with one aspect - in the actual data, some address lines contain compound info such as: '230-240 (even) james street, 14-10 (all) high street, Manchester' (all in one row) - so your solution works great to extract all the numbers but I'm still trying to figure out how to get the correct road name appended at the end.  I'm trying to figure it out but if you have any ideas I'd appreciate it!

Yes, @suzanne, I will provide you a solution for that case, within some minutes.

In my code, @suzanne, just replace x['var1'].str.extract(r'(\w+)$', expand=False) by x['var1'].str.extract(r'\)\s*(.+)$', expand=False).

@suzanne Are you sure this is doing what you expect? AFAIU, this doesn't handle the comma separated case correctly.

@mozway, that's true.  In going through the data more thoroughly there are so many variations in the address field that I've started a pre-clean of the address fields so that the fields are more regular, in which case either your solution or PaulS works without further editing.  Thanks!
